# How to resolve "no block source available"?

Tags: bitcoin-core, connection

I've got some trouble using `bitcoin-qt`.

It stays on: `"No block source available...  242 weeks behind."`
And `"Catching up ... Processed 0"` etc...
Map port using UPnP is activated, and proxy disabled and I have 7 active connections to the Bitcoin network. I tried without firewall or antivirus, but nothing happened. I went into log file and I saw this:

```
send version message: version 70001, blocks=0, us=1**.***.**.***:8333, them=*.**.****.**:8333, peer=*.****.***.****:8333
socket recv error 10054
disconnecting node 124.1
```

Don't take attention to the "*".
For each send in the logfile there is a socket recv error...

Edit :

I'm running

bitcoin-qt v0.8.3-beta
OS - windows XP pro sp3
I tried to put it off / on -> nothing else

What can I do? Thank you for your help.

Comment: I believe I am ecountering the same issue. I am on a mac, & I've tried locating the "bitcoin" folder under the "Library Support" folder as I have read on another page to delete the program files to re-install it but I am unable to locate it. Says "No block source available" upon hover "Catching up... 180200 out of 225430 (estimated) blocks of transaction history last received block was 67 weeks ago... says I have "0 active connections to the bitcoin network" it has been at this state for more than 12 hours... any help?

Comment: what is the posts 1 2 very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I was having this problem. I updated my client to the newest version (https://bitcoin.org/en/download) and it solved itself. I think the clients might stop communicating with other clients who don't update. Haven't read that anywhere or anything, just a guess.

---

The problem has returned, but updating the client is still a good thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to:

- Download the blockchain as a file and import it
- force your client to switch to other peers
- have you tried turning it off and on again?
- have you tried reinstalling it?
- have you tried putting your computer into another network?

Otherwise more information about what you have tried would be helpful, and we could use a bit more information such as, which version of the client and what operating system you are using. :)

**Edit:**
Just googled your problem again and found a [bug report](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues/956) from 2012 where a person had "socket recv error: 10054". Somebody suggested the following (Please read the whole thing before applying!):

> Take a look at (folder is hidden):
>
> C:\ProgramData\boost_interprocess\Select LastBootUpTime from Win32_OperatingSystem
>
> This one contains 2 files, 1 which consists of 32 "random" characters and looks like a hash and a BitcoinURL file of size 0. The files are there sometimes after a hard crash.
>
> Delete the whole C:\ProgramData\boost_interprocess folder, restart the client, remove the database logs from the datadir and everything will work again.
>
> It's related to stale files after a crash, which seem to come from a used lib in the Bitcoin client (some of the Boost ones).

To which the thread starter replied that it solved his problem.

**MacOS**

According to a [comment on a similar question by Neil Neyman](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/13074/5406) the respective folder can be found on MacOS at ~/Library/Application Support/Bitcoin/

To show your library directory in finder, hold the alt key while viewing the "GO" menu in the top menubar.

Comment: How can i force the client to switch to other peers ? Thanks for your help !

Comment: You can create a configuration file in your Bitcoin folder, and you'll want to use addnode=ip.ad.dr.ess.
You can find instruction here: [Running Bitcoin: Configuration File](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Running_Bitcoin#Bitcoin.conf_Configuration_File)
Otherwise I wonder, whether it might be a Windows XP problem, I mean even Service Pack 3 is five years old by now. ;)

Comment: You were probably right, changed it for W7 and no more trouble. Sorry for the delay, was on holidays.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem and I found these two posts [1](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=233943.0) [2](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=291570.msg3121362#msg3121362) very helpful. What ended up working for me was going to preferences > Network, and turning off the SOCKS proxy, and then restarting the program. After that the network started to synchronize.

Comment: Loourr, You solution worked for me. Thanks. However, is it important that I have Socks Proxy turned on - on my own home network?