# Bitcoin QT "No block source available"... stuck at "180200 out of 225430"

Tags: bitcoin-core, mac

I have downloaded Bitcoin-qt and have encountered similar problems that others have on here. However, the offered solutions don't apply to me, because I run Mac OS.

I get a status message that says "*No block source available*", when hovering over "*Catching up... 180200 out of 225430 (estimated) blocks of transaction history last received block was 67 weeks ago...*" the client informs me that I have "*0 active connections to the bitcoin network*". My client has been in this state for more than 12 hours. I've tried locating the "bitcoin" folder in the "Library Support" folder as I have read on another page to delete the program files to re-install & attempt to re-index the block but I am unable to locate it the bitcoin file... any help?

Comment: The osx data directory is ~/Library/Application Support/Bitcoin/ To show your library directory in finder, hold the alt key while viewing the "GO" menu in the top menubar.

Comment: perhaps you are based somewhere where there is unlikely to be that many other nodes... North Korea? Burma? Are you sure you really have a network connection? And PLEASE state what version you are on.