# socket recv error Connection reset by peer (54) failed after select(): Connection refused (61)

Tags: bitcoin-core

> No block source available

I have:

```
nmap -Pn 84.236.43.229
```

For each of the addresses in question none of them have had port 8333 open, I have also tried testing from outside my current network, and also do not see port 8333 to be open.

I took a blind stab at deleting `peers.dat` not knowing what it was used for.

It's failing here:

- https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/5233aefa3f52bdf7847b585610a45e6b97fbb17e/src/netbase.cpp#L446

What am I missing?

- macosx 10.11.6
- bitcoin-core 0.13.1

A more complete debug.log:

```
2016-12-22 21:02:05 Loading addresses from DNS seeds (could take a while)
2016-12-22 21:02:18 socket recv error Connection reset by peer (54)
2016-12-22 21:02:18 connect() to 37.48.70.149:8333 failed after select(): Connection refused (61)
2016-12-22 21:02:19 socket recv error Connection reset by peer (54)
2016-12-22 21:02:20 socket recv error Connection reset by peer (54)
2016-12-22 21:02:20 socket recv error Connection reset by peer (54)
2016-12-22 21:02:21 connect() to [2a01:cb08:232:dd00:8c0f:9947:bb30:7cf0]:8333 failed: No route to host (65)
2016-12-22 21:02:21 socket recv error Connection reset by peer (54)
2016-12-22 21:02:22 socket recv error Connection reset by peer (54)
2016-12-22 21:02:23 socket recv error Connection reset by peer (54)
2016-12-22 21:02:23 socket recv error Connection reset by peer (54)
2016-12-22 21:02:24 socket recv error Connection reset by peer (54)
2016-12-22 21:02:25 socket recv error Connection reset by peer (54)
2016-12-22 21:02:25 socket recv error Connection reset by peer (54)
2016-12-22 21:02:26 socket recv error Connection reset by peer (54)
2016-12-22 21:02:27 socket recv error Connection reset by peer (54)
2016-12-22 21:02:28 socket recv error Connection reset by peer (54)
2016-12-22 21:02:29 socket recv error Connection reset by peer (54)
2016-12-22 21:02:29 socket recv error Connection reset by peer (54)
2016-12-22 21:02:30 connect() to 175.171.182.204:8333 failed after select(): Connection refused (61)
2016-12-22 21:02:31 socket recv error Connection reset by peer (54)
2016-12-22 21:02:31 socket recv error Connection reset by peer (54)
2016-12-22 21:02:32 socket recv error Connection reset by peer (54)
2016-12-22 21:02:37 124 addresses found from DNS seeds
2016-12-22 21:02:37 dnsseed thread exit
2016-12-22 21:02:38 socket recv error Connection reset by peer (54)
2016-12-22 21:02:39 connect() to [2001::5ef5:79fd:244d:2b18:4de5:4a67]:8333 failed: No route to host (65)
2016-12-22 21:02:39 socket recv error Connection reset by peer (54)
2016-12-22 21:02:51 socket recv error Connection reset by peer (54)
2016-12-22 21:03:03 connect() to 155.254.235.122:8333 failed after select(): Connection refused (61)
2016-12-22 21:03:04 connect() to 46.148.16.202:8333 failed after select(): Connection refused (61)
2016-12-22 21:03:04 socket recv error Connection reset by peer (54)
2016-12-22 21:03:05 connect() to [2001::9d38:6abd:10e9:1cc7:2d94:807d]:8333 failed: No route to host (65)
2016-12-22 21:03:05 socket recv error Connection reset by peer (54)
2016-12-22 21:03:06 socket recv error Connection reset by peer (54)
2016-12-22 21:03:12 connect() to [2a02:810d:ec0:5141:8cb4:75ca:a1f3:4ff0]:8333 failed: No route to host (65)
2016-12-22 21:03:13 socket recv error Connection reset by peer (54)
2016-12-22 21:03:19 socket recv error Connection reset by peer (54)
2016-12-22 21:03:25 socket recv error Connection reset by peer (54)
2016-12-22 21:03:26 connect() to 115.197.138.242:8333 failed after select(): Connection refused (61)
2016-12-22 21:03:27 socket recv error Connection reset by peer (54)
2016-12-22 21:03:38 socket recv error Connection reset by peer (54)
2016-12-22 21:03:39 socket recv error Connection reset by peer (54)
2016-12-22 21:03:40 socket recv error Connection reset by peer (54)
2016-12-22 21:03:40 socket recv error Connection reset by peer (54)
2016-12-22 21:03:47 socket recv error Connection reset by peer (54)
2016-12-22 21:03:57 socket recv error Connection reset by peer (54)
2016-12-22 21:04:09 socket recv error Connection reset by peer (54)
2016-12-22 21:04:10 socket recv error Connection reset by peer (54)
2016-12-22 21:04:10 socket recv error Connection reset by peer (54)
2016-12-22 21:04:11 socket recv error Connection reset by peer (54)
2016-12-22 21:04:18 socket recv error Connection reset by peer (54)
2016-12-22 21:04:19 socket recv error Connection reset by peer (54)
2016-12-22 21:04:20 socket recv error Connection reset by peer (54)
2016-12-22 21:04:20 connect() to [2a02:908:953:b20:1ca0:29c9:5a47:7e95]:8333 failed: No route to host (65)
2016-12-22 21:04:21 connect() to 101.81.95.46:8333 failed after select(): Connection refused (61)
2016-12-22 21:04:22 connect() to [2001:985:3704:1:41ce:7c4b:9129:2b8d]:8333 failed: No route to host (65)
2016-12-22 21:04:22 socket recv error Connection reset by peer (54)
2016-12-22 21:04:23 socket recv error Connection reset by peer (54)
2016-12-22 21:04:35 socket recv error Connection reset by peer (54)
2016-12-22 21:04:36 socket recv error Connection reset by peer (54)
2016-12-22 21:04:42 socket recv error Connection reset by peer (54)
2016-12-22 21:04:42 socket recv error Connection reset by peer (54)
2016-12-22 21:04:43 socket recv error Connection reset by peer (54)
2016-12-22 21:04:44 connect() to [2a02:810d:843f:f4c0:1414:51b7:9ded:f2a5]:8333 failed: No route to host (65)
2016-12-22 21:04:44 socket recv error Connection reset by peer (54)
2016-12-22 21:04:45 socket recv error Connection reset by peer (54)
2016-12-22 21:04:46 connect() to 198.74.4.34:8333 failed after select(): Connection refused (61)
2016-12-22 21:04:46 socket recv error Connection reset by peer (54)
2016-12-22 21:04:52 connect() to [2003:56:c832:ea00:48c5:f2e4:df6d:f841]:8333 failed: No route to host (65)
2016-12-22 21:04:53 connect() to 70.184.247.44:8333 failed after select(): Connection refused (61)
2016-12-22 21:04:54 connect() to 85.214.120.137:8333 failed after select(): Connection refused (61)
2016-12-22 21:04:54 connect() to [2001::9d38:6ab8:811:184f:9348:8b23]:8333 failed: No route to host (65)
2016-12-22 21:04:55 connect() to 213.5.65.69:8333 failed after select(): Connection refused (61)
2016-12-22 21:04:56 socket recv error Connection reset by peer (54)
2016-12-22 21:04:56 connect() to [2601:405:8401:2710::1]:8333 failed: No route to host (65)
2016-12-22 21:04:56 connect() to [2001::9d38:90d7:18ed:65db:e700:276]:8333 failed: No route to host (65)
2016-12-22 21:04:57 socket recv error Connection reset by peer (54)
2016-12-22 21:04:58 socket recv error Connection reset by peer (54)
2016-12-22 21:05:10 socket recv error Connection reset by peer (54)
2016-12-22 21:05:10 connect() to [2001::4137:9e76:202a:3565:e8a3:7fa6]:8333 failed: No route to host (65)
2016-12-22 21:05:11 connect() to [2003:df:3bd1:be00:89e5:2c2b:6925:d672]:8333 failed: No route to host (65)
2016-12-22 21:05:11 connect() to 104.152.214.187:8333 failed after select(): Connection refused (61)
2016-12-22 21:05:23 connect() to 62.210.82.206:8333 failed after select(): Connection refused (61)
2016-12-22 21:05:23 connect() to [2003:86:440b:1c00:a015:c2a1:113f:f270]:8333 failed: No route to host (65)
2016-12-22 21:05:35 connect() to [2404:4408:1019:da00:1275:7f76:658e:d31b]:8333 failed: No route to host (65)
2016-12-22 21:05:35 connect() to [2001::5ef5:79fd:2880:3e36:fd11:58ed]:8333 failed: No route to host (65)
2016-12-22 21:05:47 connect() to [2001::5ef5:79fd:8ed:5f14:acc0:e8d]:8333 failed: No route to host (65)
2016-12-22 21:05:53 connect() to [2001::9d38:6ab8:2072:d5:474a:9040]:8333 failed: No route to host (65)
2016-12-22 21:05:53 connect() to [2001::9d38:90d7:388d:31f1:6e7d:824f]:8333 failed: No route to host (65)
2016-12-22 21:05:54 connect() to [2001::9d38:6abd:c8d:13c9:b952:bd52]:8333 failed: No route to host (65)
2016-12-22 21:06:11 connect() to [2003:86:4517:dc4d:9815:41e0:6cab:a35f]:8333 failed: No route to host (65)
2016-12-22 21:06:28 connect() to [2a02:120b:c3ce:f580:6900:215f:d8cc:bd3f]:8333 failed: No route to host (65)
2016-12-22 21:06:29 connect() to [2001::9d38:6abd:1caf:1248:da49:87cb]:8333 failed: No route to host (65)
2016-12-22 21:06:40 connect() to [2001::9d38:6abd:14be:3eb3:518f:b768]:8333 failed: No route to host (65)
2016-12-22 21:06:46 socket recv error Connection reset by peer (54)
2016-12-22 21:06:52 connect() to [2001::5ef5:79fd:1c34:29:a982:8a2]:8333 failed: No route to host (65)
2016-12-22 21:06:53 connect() to [2605:e000:d840:a00:a0f4:7145:5649:2e78]:8333 failed: No route to host (65)
2016-12-22 21:06:59 connect() to [2001::5ef5:79fb:14be:3ce7:48b9:c8f7]:8333 failed: No route to host (65)
2016-12-22 21:07:05 connect() to [2001::9d38:6abd:30bb:dbc6:4285:9e26]:8333 failed: No route to host (65)
2016-12-22 21:07:05 connect() to [2a01:e35:2ee9:a70:61cd:81c:d87a:cac1]:8333 failed: No route to host (65)
2016-12-22 21:07:06 connect() to [2001::5ef5:79fd:104f:1dca:4fe6:f853]:8333 failed: No route to host (65)
2016-12-22 21:07:31 connect() to [2001::5ef5:79fd:2cf7:d18:9d1c:2ad7]:8333 failed: No route to host (65)
2016-12-22 21:07:49 connect() to [2a02:1810:1d09:6500:1076:f642:19a6:752c]:8333 failed: No route to host (65)
2016-12-22 21:07:52 socket recv error Connection reset by peer (54)
2016-12-22 21:07:53 connect() to 185.100.85.190:8333 failed after select(): Connection refused (61)
2016-12-22 21:07:54 connect() to [2001::4137:9e76:3449:371e:892c:c45c]:8333 failed: No route to host (65)
2016-12-22 21:07:55 connect() to [2001::5ef5:79fb:1433:2cdb:269f:68af]:8333 failed: No route to host (65)
2016-12-22 21:08:03 connect() to [2001::4137:9e76:24ca:1170:413d:5564]:8333 failed: No route to host (65)
2016-12-22 21:08:10 connect() to [2001::5ef5:79fd:1c56:1f6e:6818:141d]:8333 failed: No route to host (65)
2016-12-22 21:08:13 socket recv error Connection reset by peer (54)
2016-12-22 21:08:13 connect() to 167.114.118.5:8333 failed after select(): Connection refused (61)
2016-12-22 21:08:24 connect() to [2001::5ef5:79fd:18e5:69eb:f133:e852]:8333 failed: No route to host (65)
2016-12-22 21:08:24 connect() to [2001::5ef5:79fd:14ec:e48:a3b2:c8c9]:8333 failed: No route to host (65)
2016-12-22 21:08:55 connect() to [2002:82ff:c04:2:3489:dc5c:a19c:91e3]:8333 failed: No route to host (65)
2016-12-22 21:09:17 socket recv error Connection reset by peer (54)
2016-12-22 21:09:23 connect() to [2001:14ba:7f8:9700:581e:c16:5d90:c80d]:8333 failed: No route to host (65)
2016-12-22 21:09:24 connect() to 178.0.244.53:8333 failed after select(): Connection refused (61)
2016-12-22 21:09:24 connect() to [2001::5ef5:79fb:2c8f:2552:6e87:f197]:8333 failed: No route to host (65)
2016-12-22 21:09:25 socket recv error Connection reset by peer (54)
```

related:

- [No block source available. -reindex not working](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/46050/no-block-source-available-reindex-not-working)
- [Bitcoin Core v0.12.1 wallet. Steps to diagnose "No block source available"?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/46701/bitcoin-core-v0-12-1-wallet-steps-to-diagnose-no-block-source-available)
- [Bitcoin QT "No block source available"... stuck at "180200 out of 225430"](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/13074/bitcoin-qt-no-block-source-available-stuck-at-180200-out-of-225430)
- [How to resolve "no block source available"?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/12952/how-to-resolve-no-block-source-available)