# Server cannot connect to Peers With Some Internet Connections

Tags: network

I use the internet at my work, at my house, and at various other places. The server can connect with other peers and get block data at all of these locations except for my home. What could be the reason for this? I also can't push to GitHub using SSH whenever I am at home, so I'm guessing these problems are related.

I have tried turning firewalls off, and resetting the router. I still always get the "No block source available error".

I know this is similar to the question asked [here](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/12952/how-to-resolve-no-block-source-available-and/30731#30731), but I think it is different because this question asks why it would be happening only on a particular internet connection.

Comment: What does your debug.log say? Is it trying to connect to peers?

Comment: A Gist can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/278d8100f826c922ab95), but I think the important parts might be the last three lines.

Comment: What have you got in your Bitcoin.conf file?

Comment: It happens with all of my QT wallets, regardless of .conf file. Some of them don't even have conf files.

Comment: @StephenM347 check this out: http://www.deepdotweb.com/2014/09/13/comcast-declares-war-tor/, also:https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=612973.0

Comment: @StephenM347 also make sure you shut down completely any antivirus/anti*/security* software running on your computer. Are you able to download any files through the torrent network on the computers that seem to have this issue?

Comment: @GeorgeKimionis, thank you, it seems I am getting closer to an answer. I don't have TOR enabled on my clients, though, and isn't that an opt-in part of the client? Could Comcast be blocking my bitcoin related activity even though I'm not using TOR? Thanks! (Also, you might want to post that stuff as an answer, in case it does lead me to solving my problem)

Comment: @StephenM347 it seems that quite a few Comcast subscribers face similar issues, this is why I've asked you if you are able to download torrents without a problem. ToR isn't part of the reference client but can be configured to work with it very easily and this is what I would suggest you to do if everything else fails.